# Removing JSON objects that aren't correctly formatted Python

Tags: python, json

I'm building a chatbot database atm. I uses data from [pushshift.io](http://files.pushshift.io/reddit/comments/). In order to deal with big datafile, (I understand that `json` loads everything into RAM, so if you only have 16GB RAM and working with 30GB of data, that is a nono), I wrote a bash script that split the big file into smaller chunk of 3GB of file so that I can run it through `json.loads` (or `pd.read_json`). The problem whenever I run my code it returns

```py
JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Thus I take a look into the `temp` json file that I just created and I see this happens in my JSON file:

```
ink_id":"t3_2qyr1a","body":"Most of us have some family members like this. *Most* of my family is like this. ","downs":0,"created_utc":"1420070400","score":14,"author":"YoungModern","distinguished":null,"id":"cnas8zv","archived":false,"parent_id":"t3_2qyr1a","subreddit":"exmormon","author_flair_css_class":null,"author_flair_text":null,"gilded":0,"retrieved_on":1425124282,"ups":14,"controversiality":0,"subreddit_id":"t5_2r0gj","edited":false}
```

The sample correction of the data looks like this

```
{"score_hidden":false,"name":"t1_cnas8zv","link_id":"t3_2qyr1a","body":"Most of us have some family members like this. *Most* of my family is like this. ","downs":0,"created_utc":"1420070400","score":14,"author":"YoungModern","distinguished":null,"id":"cnas8zv","archived":false,"parent_id":"t3_2qyr1a","subreddit":"exmormon","author_flair_css_class":null,"author_flair_text":null,"gilded":0,"retrieved_on":1425124282,"ups":14,"controversiality":0,"subreddit_id":"t5_2r0gj","edited":false}
```

I notice that my bash script split the file without paying attention to the JSON objects. So my question is are there ways to write a function in python that can detect JSON objects that are not correctly formatted and deleted it?

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a lot of information to go on, but I would challenge the frame a little.

There are several incremental json parsers available in Python.  A quick search shows `ijson` should allow you to traverse your very large data structure without exploding.

You also should consider another data format (or a real database), or you will easily find yourself spending time reimplementing much much slower versions of features that already exist with the right tools.

Comment: I'm not sure how to use `ijson` after searching the internet for quite a bit. I just wonder if you can write a python script that can check the format of the JSON file, for say that if an object hasn't got an appropriate `{}` it will delete it?

Comment: @AaronPham you can, but it would require writing a parser that is actually more complicated than the original json parser.  You can think of it as the little grammar / state machine from https://www.json.org/, but having to enter at any state along the way (simultaneously perhaps) in order to reject.

Comment: I gave up on working with the dataset. I will do it later on. I just need something to work on my RNN model. Thank you for the answer anw

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the [json standard library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html), then calling `json.loads` on badly formatted data will return `JSONDecodeError`. You can put your code in a try-catch statement and check if this exception occurs to make sure you only process correctly formatted data.

Comment: I already know where the problem is. The problem is that when I split the file some of the objects got split as well, therefore, there are some uncompleted JSON objects. I'm asking whether we can check the JSON file by running through the whole file, checking whether an object has an open `{` and a close `}`, if not, delete it?